# How to update versonName for an application published on Google play?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I published an application onto Google play, I've updated the versionCode however forgot to update the versionName. Is there a way to update the versionName without creating another release?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to create another release for that. Any changes even if it is great (added feature) or small (just a version name), you have to create a new release. You may want to check this documentation about [Update your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) to understand more about updating your APK in the Google Play Console.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

Version name is embedded in your Android APK, so you have to release a new APK to change the version name.

Comment: Ahh that's unfortunate, thanks for answering my question though!